# Calculating minute of the day, week, month, year

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to calculate minute of the day, week, month and year and create a column in pandas DataFrame for them?

I'm already have Date column and formatted using `pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])`

Comment: yes, you can access the `dt` element of the column get these values like so: `df.columns.dt.year`, `df.columns.dt.month` and so on.

Comment: IIUC use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298488/how-to-extract-hour-minute-and-second-from-series-filled-with-datetime-time-val)

Comment: i know how to calculate using dt. I mean i can get day of the week and etc. I'm trying to calculate minute of the day, week, month

Comment: @DonCoder - Can you ad some sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?